# ClassCastException when getting signalstrength in android

Tags: android, classcastexception, telephonymanager

In my code, I get the type of connection i.e LTE, CDMA or HSPA etc. from the telephonyManager in Android and then accordingly cast it. An example is shown below.

```
    switch(getCellInfoType()) {
        case CELL_INFO_TYPE_LTE:
             (CellInfoLte) ...
        case CELL_INFO_TYPE_CDMA:
             (CellInfoCdma) ...
```

In an area of really bad reception, where the phone continuously jumps between LTE and 3G, I get a ClassCastException. This is due to the fact that once I get the type of connection from the telephonyManager and then try to cast it (at this time it flops) I get the exception as it no longer the same instance.

For example, I get type LTE before entering the switch block, after which it falls to 3G. As I have the variable set to type LTE, I try to cast it to LTE which then throws the ClassCastException. My solution is just to catch the exception in this case and carry on (essentialy discarding this call as being faulty). Is this the cleanest way of dealing with this issue or is it possible to be able to avoid this altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the CellInfo structure then use instanceof to decide which way to handle it.

```
CellInfo info = getCellInfo();

if(info instanceof CellInfoLte){

}
else if (info instanceof CellInfoCdma){

}
```

Comment: So essentially, instead of storing it in a variable, I should each time try to see if its an instance of LTE,HSPA etc and then accordingly proceed?

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks! I'm not sure why I didn't think of this before.

Comment: Because it isn't something you shouldn't have to do. Google ought to provide 1 atomic api for this, its a bad design that they don't.  Luckily its one we can work around